# Why both "Start (Without) Debugging" (F5 anf Ctrl+F5) doesn't create CppUnit *.xml report file?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2005, cppunit

First of all, I want to welcome everybody on stackoverflow as this is my 1st question.
I got stuck with generating output *.xml file with CppUnit on Visual Studio 2005. When I run the code with F5 or Ctrl+F5 (Start Debugging or Start Without Debugging) it's not creating the report file. But when I run it "manually" (through *.exe file from /debug), the report file is created. What could be the reason?

testApp.cpp:

```
#include "Test_myFuzzy.h"

#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>
#include <cppunit/XmlOutputter.h>

int main(){
    CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;

    std::ofstream ofs("tests.xml"); 
    CppUnit::XmlOutputter* xml = new CppUnit::XmlOutputter(&runner.result(),ofs); 
    xml->setStyleSheet("report.xsl");
    runner.setOutputter(xml);

    runner.addTest(Test_myFuzzy::suite());
    runner.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ofstream ofs("tests.xml");
```

You didn't specify where the test.xml file should be created. So by default it will get created in the same folder that the exe is in.

One way to fix this is to specify where to create/find the file `"C:\test.xml"` or you do a search on your project folder because the file was probably created in the debug bin.

Comment: The file `tests.xml` is created ONLY when I run manually the `*.exe` file from `\debug` folder. It is NOT created when using F5 or Ctrl+F5 (I checked many times). I thought this actually run the program, so there should be `tests.xml` in `$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectDir)\debug`...
It is also NOT created when using `"C:\tests.xml"`